# Proving $2^{\aleph_0} = {\aleph_0}!$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

How can I show the existence of a injection $\phi:\{x|x \subset \omega \} \rightarrow \{f|f:\omega \rightarrow \omega$ is bijective$\} $?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Can you show what you have tried?

Comment: the title is irritating

Answer (score 0):

For $x \subset \omega$ let $x^* =\{n+2 : n \in x \}$. Let $\phi(x)$ be a bijection $ f:\omega \to \omega$ where $f(m)=m$ when $m \in x^*$ and $f(m) \ne m$ when $m \not \in x^*$.